# Faulting application name: LDRT.vshost.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011d445 Faulting module name: deviceassociation.dll_unloaded

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

My requirement is: i need to transfer and receive data from bluetooths.

Tested entire application in Windows XP with Bluetooth 2.0 dongle and is working fine.

Installed my application in Windows 8.1 and tested with Bluetooth 4.0 dongle and .Net framework 2.0. in this case also application working fine.

To communicate 2 bluetooths, i am using third party dll .... IntheHand.Net.Personal.dll

But, Application was closing unexpectedly with In-built bluetooth.

I am using Lenova Laptop, Windows 8.1.

In-built Bluetooth info are -

Local Address : 3423870DBF42

Name : XXXXXXXXXXXXX

Hci version : v4_0

Lmp sub version : 6

Lmp version : v4_0

Manufacturer : RalinkTechnology

Software Manufacturer : Microsoft

Class of Device : 1A010C

Device Name : LaptopComputer

Device Name : Network, Capturing, ObjectTransfer

After closing the application, when i verified in Event log .. showing following information

Faulting application name: LDRT.vshost.exe, version: 11.0.50727.1, time stamp: 0x5011d445

Faulting module name: deviceassociation.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x501089ed

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x000007febee92113

Faulting process id: 0x3c8

Faulting application start time: 0x01cfd7b5ce6d3bc3

Faulting application path: D:\LDRT23Jul2014\LDRT\bin\Debug\LDRT.vshost.exe

Faulting module path: deviceassociation.dll

Report Id: 7fddc3fc-43ac-11e4-be8e-a01d486cdbee

Faulting package full name:

Faulting package-relative application ID:

Please suggest me.. to resolve this error...

Comment: Trying to connect both bluetooths, i am getting following error (Note: In my 2 hours testing, got only once.)

Faulting application name: LDRT.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5423dd87
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000007febee92113
Faulting process id: 0x%9
Faulting application start time: 0x%10
Faulting application path: %11
Faulting module path: %12
Report Id: %13
Faulting package full name: %14
Faulting package-relative application ID: %15

Comment: Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: LDRT.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5423dd87
P4: unknown
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 00000000
P7: c0000005
P8: 000007febee92113
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\LDRT\AppData\Local\Temp\WER4AE4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_LDRT.exe_815522c81f63d8d188f979242cf4a8aefd04_1e3c5acc

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: ce48cff4-4543-11e4-be8e-3423870dbf42
Report Status: 97
Hashed bucket: